# Navigator.pop seems to be triggered on orientation change

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

I have a page where the camera starts and I can record a video. The problem is when I rotate the camera. Then I end up in the main page. This also happens if I navigate to other pages and the change orientation.

Before adding the camera feature I enforced portrait mode so I did not discover this behaviour.

How can I avoid `Navigator.pop` when the orientation changes?

I am btw a rookie in Flutter.

EDIT: I have tried some different approaches, like adding `WillPopScope`. However, that is not triggered when rotating the camera.

It does work to navigate to the camera view using this approach:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CameraView()),
  (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
);
```

But then there is no back button...

How can this be so complicated?

This is how I add navigation in the HomePage:

```
Widget startResultButton() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: _buttonWidthFactor,
        heightFactor: _buttonHeightFactor,
        child: TextButton(
          style: getStyle(buttonColor),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return const ResultsMenuView();
                },
              ),
            ).then((value) => _updateDisplay());
          },
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Flexible(child: getSvg("prev_sessions.svg")),
              const Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                "Analyse results",
                textScaleFactor: textFactor,
              )),
            ],
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And the `ResultMainView` looks like:

```
class ResultsMenuView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ResultsMenuView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final double _buttonWidth = 0.9;
  final double _heightFactor = 0.6;
  Widget getBody() {
    var sessionChart = Flexible(
      child: NavigationButton(
          "Session Overview",
          buttonColor,
          const SessionOverviewChart(),
          _buttonWidth,
          _heightFactor,
          "overall_results.svg"),
    );
    var detailedChart = Flexible(
      child: NavigationButton(
          "Detailed Scores",
          buttonColor,
          const DetailedChartView(),
          _buttonWidth,
          _heightFactor,
          "detailed_results.svg"),
    );
    var tableView = Flexible(
      child: NavigationButton("History", buttonColor, const TableView(),
          _buttonWidth, _heightFactor, "prev_sessions.svg"),
    );
    var trendCurveButton = Flexible(
      child: NavigationButton(
          "Trend Curve",
          buttonColor,
          const TrendCurveView(),
          _buttonWidth,
          _heightFactor,
          "trend_curve.svg"),
    );
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [sessionChart, detailedChart, trendCurveButton, tableView],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: buttonColor,
        title: const Text("Results Menu"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: getBody(),
      ),
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    );
  }
}
```